# Does SQL Server 2008 R2 Express expire?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Q: Does SQL Server 2008R2 expire?

What happens is:

1. My pages crash out of the blue
2. I cannot connect with mgmt studio or query analyzer with previous setup.
3. When i go to the server and try the management studio installed there it says it's expired.
4. Of course when I try to read the License Agreement from Sql Server installation center it is greyed out.
5. I can't start the SQL Server Service.

It's looking REALLY bad for me here.

Comment: Have you read the FAQ on this site (http://stackoverflow.com/faq)? I guess no as I don't see any relation to programming in your question.

Comment: Soubds like you are running some kind of beta or other pre release code.

Comment: just FYI - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/f0f854dd-a7b2-45ec-9adf-0aa44de32c5c

Comment: Let's move this to Server Fault - admins may be able to give you better help than we can on licensing and expiration.

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting message when connecting the instance as 'expired' means you have installed Enterprise Evaluation edition which will expire automatically within 180 days.

Do you have database backup for this instance?
If so you can purchase Enterprise or Standard edition and restore those databases back. Otherwise if you are intended to use 2008 R2 SQLExpress only then ensure database size is not more than 10GB and beyond.
Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx fyi.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Express edition is free and does not expire.  Like Ben Robinson said in his comment, it sounds like you've installed something non-Express that was either pre-release or evaluation.  Did you install Management Studio Express as well, or is it the full edition Management Studio?

What errors do you get when starting the service.  Also, look in the Application and System event logs for SQL related log events.

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed EVALUATION Edition. It expires after 180 days.

Here is a STEP BY STEP look at 
[HOW TOP FIX: SQL Server Express Evaluation Edition Expires And Property Owner Is Not Available](http://www.smattie.com/2012/04/15/how-to-fix-sql-server-express-evaluation-edition-expired-and-property-owner-is-not-available/)